# Problem with Beamer when I create some basic Slide

Tags: beamer, miktex-update

I have a problem when I try to create some basic slides with **Beamer class**.

This started when I update the **MiKTeX 2.9.6360** (It was on february 26, 2018). One of the updated package  was Beamer. It's the firstime that this happen to me. I always work with Beamer.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Title} % Enter your title between curly braces
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Slide}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
First Content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now the data of compilation showed:

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "abiertos.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(abiertos.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamer.cls"
Document Class: beamer 2018/02/20 v3.50 A class for typesetting presentations
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasedecode.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex"

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 F
     ILE0   Ö®:ñ        8   ˆ                   èÿ    n         `           ...

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on abiertos.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

It seems that all is in order with packages. It could be a code of page problem, but I don't Know. I will be greatful for your help.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the encoding, the symbols in the log file look strange. Make a backup of your file first. If you save your file with a new name, does it work? Can you copy the content of your tex file and copy it to a new file?

Comment: "It could be a code of page problem" Can't understand this sentence but adding this comment to say that your code compiles fine.

Comment: No problem here using TeXlive2017 on linux, updated today Feb, 26, including Beamer.

Comment: Perhaps one file has been corrupted during the download. Try to deinstall and reinstall the pgf package (with the package manager (admin)).

Comment: Ulrike Fischer that was the problem: the pgf package was corrupted. I deinstall and reinstall the package and the problem was solved. Thanks

Comment: To ping somebody you need to use the `@` symbol e.g. @UlrikeFischer ^^.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the file `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex"` has been corrupted.

So the best is to deinstall and reinstall the `pgf` package with the package manager (admin version, as the original file is in `C:\Program Files`).